# ionic3 - slow navigation after upgrade

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I upgraded my application to work with ionic 3 and Angular 4 and after that each navigation on my application became really slow.

My code hasn't changed. When I debugged it I saw the code is arriving at `nav.push(SomePage)`, nothing happens for a second or so and then the page is pushed.

I didn't add support for lazy-loading.

Helppp I don't want to downgrade :(

**Update**
Updated my package.json to the latest ionic 3.4.0 and it didn't work.
Pleaseee helpppp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem and it was **not due to upgrade**.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-slow-navigation-after-upgrading/94494